# Running node.js app on aws ec2 instance with https

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-ec2, https, server

I uploaded my node.js app with ec2 AWS instance, my app.ts running on port 5000, I allowed within inbound rules HTTPS on port 443, also I bought have a domain with route 53 amazon, when I'm trying to send a request to https://ec2-3-example.com am getting err connection refused but when I'm sending a request with http://ec2-3-example.com:5000 locally I get the data from the server, how do I solve this?
thanks in advance I can share the code if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have access to your app via HTTPS, you will have to attach an SSL certificate to a reverse proxy somewhere in the middle of the system.

The problem you are experiencing is that you are opening port `443` in the EC2 instance, but your application is running on port `5000`. On top of that, SSL termination will not be done automatically. You will need a reverse proxy like ALB or Nginx.

One way of doing it in your case could be:

- Check that your app runs on port `5000` in an EC2 instance
- Create an ALB and add your EC2 instance to it
- Attach an SSL Certificate to your ALB with the corresponding domain
- Allow inbound traffic on port `5000` in the security group of your EC2 instance, from your ALB
- Allow inbound traffic on port `443` for the ALB
- Route traffic from your domain on Route53 to your ALB